# Extra whitespaces in clipboard with TeamViewer

Tags: ubuntu, clipboard, teamviewer

I'm connecting from Windows to an Ubuntu computer (and vice versa) and I'm copy-pasting values from one to another. The strange problem is the text I copied usually ends up with a lot of blank characters after it.

So I copy something (to be exact, plain text from local Notepad++ to remote MATLAB command window) from my Windows machine, and I paste it to remote Ubuntu, and I see tens (maybe hundreds) of whitespace attached in the end of it.

Not sure how to give an example or reproduce the error, so I'm hoping that someone had a similar problem and knows a solution for it :)

Thanks for any help,

Comment: So e.g. 10 lines will copy normally, but have 10 blank lines after it? Have you tried copying to another target, like a text editor in ubuntu, or the MATLAB script editor?

Comment: @jiggunjer I was only trying with a single line, now I tried multiple lines and saw that only the last line gets extra whitespaces attached. Also I tried pasting into remote GEdit, and there is no problem there. So the problem can be caused by MATLAB.